# MySQL: find all users with a given permission for a db

Tags: mysql, permissions

Looking for a query to find all users who have a given permission (EG execute) for a given database.

Rationale: cleaning up ancient stored procedures and want to know who might be using them.

I can imagine a plug-n-chug SP where I loop through all the values returned from "show grants for xxx" but I'm hoping there is a better way.

Comment: Look into the data in `mysql.user` table - I believe it stores the information you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from mysql.user where `Execute_priv` = 'Y'
```

Replace `Execute_priv` with the column name of the other priviledges you're after

For privileges on a DB by DB basis, try querying the mysql.db table:

```
select * from mysql.db where `Db` = 'databasename' and `Execute_priv` = 'Y'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a DB by DB basis?

Comment: I believe you can check the mysql.db table for priviledges on a db by db basis, I've updated the answer